# serializeArray() into an array is not producing expected output

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple forms on a page and I'm trying to use jquery to build the inputs from those forms into one JSON structure to POST. Let's say it looks like this:

```js
function submitData() {
  var serializedData = []
  var forms = $("form");

  forms.each(function(i) {
    serializedData.push({
      i: $(this).serializeArray()
    });
  });

  console.log(serializedData);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Learner</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Period</th>
      <th scope="col">Subject</th>
      <th scope="col">Teacher</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <form>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="learner"></td>
        <td><input type="date" name="date"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="period"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="subject"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="staff"></td>
        <td><button type="button">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    </form>
    <form>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="learner"></td>
        <td><input type="date" name="date"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="period"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="subject"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="staff"></td>
        <td><button type="button">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    </form>
    <form>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="learner"></td>
        <td><input type="date" name="date"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="period"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="subject"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="staff"></td>
        <td><button type="button">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    </form>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" onclick="submitData()">Submit Data</button>
```

What I'm trying to do is build JSON from the form values. This correctly builds the **structure** I'm looking for but weirdly only populates data from the first form. I.E. I get this:

```
[{
  "i": [{
    "name": "learner",
    "value": "My Name"
  }]
},{
  "i":  []
}]
```

Why might it skip the data from the second (and subsequent) forms, but work as I expect for the first one?

Comment: it works perfectly:`[{"i":[{"name":"learner","value":"a"}]},{"i":[{"name":"learner","value":"b"}]}]`

Comment: I placed your code in to an executable snippet where the output works fine. If you're still encountering this issue, please edit the question to show a more accurate sample of your code which produces the issue

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak not for me it doesn't!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'll change the table to be the actual table. The javascript is already the exact JS I'm using.

Comment: Thank you for editing. The problem is because your HTML is invalid. You cannot have `form` elements as the child of a `tbody`. If you inspect the DOM you'll see that the `form` elements have been moved and now have no content. You would need to put the `form` *outside* the `table`, although this in turn means you cannot have multiple `form` elements around each row. If you need the latter, you cannot use a `table` for this layout..

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ah. Well that was an easy answer then. Alright thanks - post as answer for sweet sweet karma :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because your HTML is invalid. You cannot have `form` elements as the child of a `tbody`. If you inspect the DOM you'll see that the `form` elements have been moved and now have no content, hence the empty output from `serializeArray()`.

To make this work you would need to put the `form` *outside* the `table`, although this in turn means you cannot have multiple `form` elements around each row. If you need the latter, you cannot use a `table` for this layout.

Comment: Thank you! I will recreate the table with Bootstrap `<container>`, `<col>` and `<row>`